# Why my YouTube video downloader only downloads some videos and for other videos it shows keyerror like URL and cipher?

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to make a YouTube video downloader using Python pytube3 but it doesn't download all the videos. Some videos download very easily but some videos won't download and instead of download it shows error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tarun\PycharmProjects\YTDownloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 297, in apply_descrambler
    for format_item in formats
  File "C:\Users\tarun\PycharmProjects\YTDownloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 297, in <listcomp>
    for format_item in formats
KeyError: 'url'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/tarun/PycharmProjects/YTDownloader/YTD.py", line 15, in video_download
    my_video = YouTube(input_user)
  File "C:\Users\tarun\PycharmProjects\YTDownloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.descramble()
  File "C:\Users\tarun\PycharmProjects\YTDownloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 132, in descramble
    apply_descrambler(self.player_config_args, fmt)
  File "C:\Users\tarun\PycharmProjects\YTDownloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 301, in apply_descrambler
    parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
  File "C:\Users\tarun\PycharmProjects\YTDownloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 301, in <listcomp>
    parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
KeyError: 'cipher'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide the code that is triggering the download?

Comment: Kindly share the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an error in the file extract.py from [pytube](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

1. Go to the location where the package was installed. If you don't know where, run the command

   ```
   pip show pytube3
   ```

   And it'll give you something like this:

[image: pip show package]

We can see `Location: c:\users\tiago\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`.

2. Go to that location, open the folder pytube and the file extract.py

[image: pythube location]

3. In the file, line no. 306 or 301, you will find `parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"])`. If yes, then change `"cipher"` to `"signatureCipher"` (make sure 'C' is capital).

   So, you'll initially have

   ```
    cipher_url = [
                    parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
                ]
   ```

   but it should be

   ```
    cipher_url = [
                    parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
                ]
   ```

[image: pytube extract cypher error fixed]

4. Run the following script to see it working

   ```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Mon Jun 15 12:21:49 2020

    @author: tiago
    """
    from pytube import YouTube

    video_url = "https://youtu.be/gp5tziO5lXg" # YouTube video URL
    youtube = YouTube(video_url)
    video = youtube.streams.first()
    video.download("C:/Users/tiago/Desktop/videos/") # Path where to store the video
   ```

You'll then see the video downloaded in that folder

[image: How to download video from YouTube in Python]

Comment: Hi Shiven, Thank you for your answer, please consider providing a path to the file that needs editing, and please wrap your code in ` signs. Happy geeking!

Comment: You are most welcome. I think YouTube has recently changed their signature styles on some videos and pytube3 has not received any upgrade so this error is generating. But this fix is working.

Comment: Working for me too ->  pytube (pytube3)

Comment: Thanks. As a side note: I have been trying to download directly in cmd, like "pytube link". After applying this solution, it says "Loading video..." then it aborts. But interestingly, when added "--resolution 720p" after it, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just go to the `pytube\extract.py` (in *pytube* library) file.
   The path of file will be (in *Windows*): `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py`
2. Open `extract.py` file and search for line:

   `parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)`
3. Now replace '`cipher`' with '`signatureCipher`'.
4. Save it.
5. Now run your code again

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with pytube3, I believe as of now they have not submitted a fix yet.
[Here is the link to the issue on github](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/641)

Comment: yeah but it won't download those videos which has offline download button disabled otherwise it works fine with other videos who has offline download button enable..can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are getting error as Keyerror:"cipher", then go to location of pytube open extract.py and on line no.301 you will get this

```
cipher_url = [
                parse_qs(formats[i]["Cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
            ]
```

now edit this line to this

```
cipher_url = [
                parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
            ]
```

save the changes and....Boom you are done.
now try downloading the video you won't get any error now.

Answer (score -1):

in pytube library ,there is a extract.py file
in this file change the cipher to signaturecipher