# How to install pytube3 in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda, pytube

In a quest to install pytube3 in Anaconda, searched for that package but couldn't find it

[image: No pytube in Anaconda]

Then, went to Anaconda Prompt and ran

```
conda install pytube3
```

[image: No pytube in Anaconda prompt]

None of this worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to open Spyder and run the following in your kernel

```
pip install pytube3
```

Then, Restart kernel and you'll be able to use it just fine.

Now, if you run

```
pip show pytube3
```

you'll see something like this

[image: pytube yey]

If then you try to download a file and get an error

```
  File "C:\Users\tiago\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 301, in <listcomp>
    parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)

KeyError: 'cipher'
```

then [this answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115943/5675325).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to install via Anaconda Prompt, try: `conda install -c conda-forge pytube`. See [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytube) reference for more details.