# Can't open downloaded .mp4 files downloaded with requests and urllib

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, urllib, mp4

I've downloaded some files using [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp5tziO5lXg&feature=youtu.be'
video_name = url.split('/')[-1]

print("Downloading file:%s" % video_name)

# download the url contents in binary format
r = requests.get(url)

# open method to open a file on your system and write the contents
with open('saved.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

and using [urllib.requests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp5tziO5lXg&feature=youtu.be'
video_name = url.split('/')[-1]

print("Downloading file:%s" % video_name)

# Copy a network object to a local file
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "saved2.mp4")
```

When I then try to open the .mp4 file I get the following error

> Cannot play
>
> This file cannot be played. This can happen because the file type is
>   not supported, the file extension is incorrect or the file is
>   corrupted.
>
> 0xc00d36c4

[image: Cannot open .mp4 file]

If I test it with [pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115943/5675325) it works fine.

What's wrong with the other methods?

Comment: You are dowloading a web page, not a video... Thanks for the musical discovery anyway ;)

Comment: You can have a look at how [youtube_dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/) does it, it's written in Python - or directly use it.

Comment: Interesting library @ThierryLathuille, having only youtube in their name makes it look less valuable than what it really is considering they work also for Google Drive, Dropbox, etc. Would be great if it also worked with One Drive too!

Comment: The problem it solves is to get to the video data starting from the Youtube page. Every site that provides videos will do it in a different way, so you will have to use specific code.

Comment: They mention to support more websites other than YouTube - http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, with the other methods it is not downloading the video but the page. What you may be obtaining is an html file with an mp4 file extension.

Therefore, it gives that error when trying to open the file.

If [pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115943/5675325) works for what you need, I would suggest using that one.

If you want to download videos from other platforms, you might consider [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/).

Answer (score -2):

Hello you can import IPython.display for audio diplay

```
import IPython.display as ipd
ipd.Audio(video_name)
```

regards
I hope I can have solved your problem