# pytube isn't downloading any videos

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I have installed pytube3 and all working well, I have created this:

```
import pytube as pt




def downloadVideo(url):
    pt.YouTube(url).streams.first().download('/Downloads')
    print("Done")
```

For some reason, it doesn't download it. Does it download somewhere else? Is there a default?
Am I typing the download location wrong?

Comment: Where are you passing the url value?

Comment: outside the def, it's still an http link

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098925/why-my-youtube-video-downloader-only-downloads-some-videos-and-for-other-videos